# Add Cron Job to Fedora Server

Tags: linux, cron, fedora

How do i add 2 cron for Fedora ami in AWS, where i need to run one cron twice a day and other one would be if data is added to the DB.

Pleas guide me from the begging coz this cron concept and the handling it is new for me

Answer (score 3):

For the first task, enter `crontab -e` and add following line in the editor:

```
0 0,12 * * * /path/to/script >/path/to/output.log 2>&1
```

so the script it run at 00:00 and 12:00.

For the second case, remember that cron is a scheduler. You need to know what time to run it at. So basically you cannot cron it unless you know exact time when it should run. If you do, add it like in my example as a second line.

See more about crontab syntax for example from here: http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

I would suggest looking at this blog post too which should get you up to speed quickly with the concepts around cron and how it works.

- [Newbie: Intro to cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, How do u I run PHP url in the cron do i have to use 'wget', if so how would i use from my scenario

Comment: Hi, this was a generic answer to add a script to cron. Please file a new question if you need help in creating a script for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support this gave me a good idea to start plus http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml this link gave me clear idea about cron and step by step instruction